# Warp around a curve/specific edge with proportional fall off

Tags: modeling, modifiers, procedural

I am probably missing something obvious, but after two days of searching and attempts could not figure it out.

I am trying to procedurally create a mesh from Megascan's opacity map. The mesh should have cylindrical volume, i.e. creating a card is easy, but is not what I want in this example.

My procedure is:

- take opacity map and generate a path from the selection in GIMP;
- export path into SVG and import into Blender as curve;
- convert curve to mesh, fill faces, and retopo into quads.

As a result of the foregoing steps, I end up with decent geometry, but it is a flat plane.

[image: Flat plane mesh with the selected faces roughly repenting the spine]

(Image above: Flat plane mesh with the selected faces roughly respresenting the spine)

The problem is how to procedurally warp/bend this twig shape around its imaginary spine in order to make it a half-cylinder on Z axis. You could achieve something similar by selecting the edges/faces representing the spine and then pushing them upward with proportional edit turned on. However, I would like to do this non-destructively. Simple deform and warp modifiers affect the whole mesh, not the geometry along the spine. I also tried weight painting the spine, using displacement and then smoothing - the result is no good. I am sure there must be a way to create a curve that will work as a spine and tell Blender to warp faces of the mesh around and along this curve with proportional fall off.

In the end I want to get geometry as in the example below in the most procedural way.

[image]

Grateful for any tips or comments.

[image]

Comment: Hello, have you tried the skin modifier + subdivision surface modifier with the stem as connected edges ?

Comment: @Gorgious, have tried it but had to kill Blender process in this case: too much calculation.

Comment: If you use a reasonable amount of vertices blender should not hang. Could you provide a sample of what you used to generate your twig with the skin modifier ?

Comment: @Gorgious Looking at the description in Blender manual I understand that skin will auto-generate geometry around the stem rather than wrapping my plane as I want it to. I should say that I gotta preserve the original shape of the plane, because I will UV project it on Megascan's atlas. At least this is the idea.

Comment: It seems that the only viable option is the skin modifier.+subsurf. As expected, it requires a lot of manual work and clean up. Apparently, there is no way achieve the automatization that I was looking for without coding a script.